# How to mock a JdbcTemplate with Mockito static factory method?

Tags: java, mockito

I'm working on a project which transitively brings a very old version of Mockito. I've updated POM to Mockito Core 5.5 and it's now the only Mockito version in my local repo. However, I'm getting inconsistent results in a legacy test, which worked with previous configuration. I've reduced my problem to the bare minimum to focus on the issue.

- TestNG 6.14
- Mockito 5.5.0
- ResponseEntity and JdbcTemplate are Spring classes. I have two Spring Framework jars in the
  classpath: 4.3 and 5.3. I'm assuming this is not material to the issue.
- JDK 17. Project at version 11.

  ```
   @Test  //TestNG annotation
   public class MyClassTest {
       // Appears to be mocked just fine
       private ResponseEntity<MyClass> responseEntityMock = mock(ResponseEntity.class);

       // Does not get mocked
       private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateMock = mock(JdbcTemplate.class)

       @Test  //TestNG annotation
       public void test() {
           ...
       }

   }
  ```

responseEntityMock shows as "Mock for ...., hashcode: 12345" in my IDE. jdbcTemplateMock is an instance but not a Mock.

Debugging takes me to the `InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker` class. Immediately following this instruction `this.mocks.put(instance, mockMetodInterceptor)`, instance for responseEntityMock becomes a Mock but instance for jdbcTemplateMock remains as is. I see no errors, anywhere.

Comment: Perhaps try using the interface [JdbcOperations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html) instead of JdbcTemplate?

Comment: I am hoping to find out what the issue is. Some other classes don't get mocked, either. I would also like to keep my change-set small, so that my pull request is about upgrading Mockito and not about reworking the test suite.

Comment: "I have two Spring Framework jars in the classpath: 4.3 and 5.3" I'm assuming this means you have two versions of JdbcTemplate on the classpath? This may well cause an issue with mockito / bytebuddy classloading